# CXF:Message part request was not recognized. (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have developed  Web services Application based on  Apache CXF.
Its working fine when used with SOAP UI , but when i tried using it with APIGEE it started giving me this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Message part request was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: hmmm - having the same problem but **with** soapui.